# Symfony4 PHPSpreadSheet gives me twice the results from a foreach loop

Tags: symfony4, phpspreadsheet

i got an issue with the following code :

```
/**
 * @Route("/dl", name="dl_xls")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 */
public function exportXLS()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $query = $em->getRepository('App:Post')
        ->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u.title')
        ->getQuery();

    $result = $query->getResult();

    $phpExcelObject = $this->get('phpspreadsheet')->createSpreadsheet();

    $row = 1;
    foreach ($result as $item) {
        $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A' . $row, $item['title']);
        $row++;
    }


    $writer = $this->get('phpspreadsheet')->createWriter($phpExcelObject, 'Csv');
    /*var_dump($writer);*/
    $writer->save("php://output");

    $response = $this->get('phpspreadsheet')->createStreamedREsponse($writer);

    $dispositionHeader = $response->headers->makeDisposition(
        ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        'resultat.xls'
    );

    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8');
    $response->headers->set('Pragma', 'public');
    $response->headers->set('Cache-control', 'maxage=1');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $dispositionHeader);

    return $response;

}
```

This code is giving me an xls file with the result of my database. The issue is that it gives me twice every result.

ps: i already check my database and my entries are not duplicated inside.

Comment: have you tried printing you array `$result` before looping on it?

Comment: yes and i got unique results. i found a solution not sure if it's the prettiest but i did change the loop to : `foreach ($result as $key=>$value) {
            echo $result[$key]['title'] . "\n";
        } ` and it did actually works as intended.